# Cannot Connect to internet via WiFi on Galaxy Tab

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab

I enabled my laptop as a hotspot and connected my tablet through WiFi. Then I turned WiFi on and it shows me the network but it tells me I'm not in range.

After that it shows network disabled and poor connection. How do I get over this?

Comment: It would help to know what you used on your laptop to create the WiFi hotspot. Could it be the software used only provides Ad-Hoc access? This is currently unsupported by Android, though it's on the wishlist for years...

Answer (score 0):

If the hotspot ssid shows in your Android device means, definitely it wont be an Ad-Hoc network. Most probably the the problem would be getting DHCP ip from your laptop. Try giving static ip to both hotspot network and your android device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Wifi Settings > Advanced > Uncheck the option titled "Avoid poor connections".

That will probably get rid of the "Poor connection prompt."